# Deleting test users using Facebook C# API

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have been successful in creating test users for my console-based application using:

```
public dynamic CreateTestUser(string name)
{
     return client.Post(APP_ID + 
          "/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=" + 
          name + 
          "&permissions=read_stream");
}
```

However, now I'm trying to delete the users that I have created and have not had success.

One method I've tried is the following:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
dynamic result = client.Delete(userId);
```

Another method I've tried is to Post:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
dynamic result = client.Post(userId + "?method=delete&access_token=...");
```

When I try the first method, I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
```

When I try the second method, I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: Facebook.FacebookApiException: (453) A session key is required for calling this method.
```

So, how can I delete my test users using the Facebook C# API?

Comment: adding method=delete in parameters is not supported. when the parameter contains method it assumes it is a legacy rest api.

Answer (score 1):

Per the error message returned by Facebook (453) need to provide an access token. The correct code is:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = client.Delete(userId);
```